# Eclipse : no "Validation" pane in the preferences

Tags: eclipse, validation, ide, preferences

I downloaded Eclipse Classic from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ and I just realized I had no Validation panel.

Is there a way to have one ? How ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by adding `org.eclipse.wst.validation.ui_1.2.204.v201004150700.jar` and `org.eclipse.wst.validation_1.2.302.v201107140600` in the plugins.